# how to override after_sign_in_path_for and after_sign_out_path_for ? And what is the use of protect_from_forgery in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to rails and just come across this can anyone tell me where and how to define these functions if I want to change my redirect hooks.
And what is the need of the protect_from_forgery in devise ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own sessions controller and override the methods:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # add your logic here.
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    # add your logic here.
  end
end
```

In `routes.rb` add the below declaration:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: "sessions"}
```